# iOS - Firebase Crash Reporting Setup Crashes XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I am working with XCode 7.3 and when I try to integrate Firebase Crash Reporting to my iOS project, XCode crashes. Things I have done so far

1. Included pod **'Firebase/Crash'**
2. In AppDelegate - Added **FIRApp.configure()**
3. Generated private key from Firebase console and downloaded.
4. Added the JSON downloaded to the root folder of project in a new folder
5. In XCode Build Phases, added a new run script with

   `GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:xxxx:ios:xxxxx
    ${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym“${SRCROOT}”/folderInRoot/filename.json`
6. When I try to **navigate** to AppDelegate to try out a crash, XCode crashes immediately.

Steps taken to resolve:

1. Tried cleaning the project.
2. Tried moving the downloaded JSON into the XCode project.
3. Tried moving the downloaded JSON to a local path and deleted it from project folder.
4. Tried running the project without navigating to any file, after adding the build script - the run succeeds and app runs in simulator just fine. Can't navigate to any file to continue working on the project though.
5. Tried deleting the run script - This allows me to navigate to other files without any XCode crashes.

Other info:

- I have Firebase Analytics already integrated and working fine.
- I also have Fabric integrated. But it is managed by a team who was working on the project before me and I just can't remove their Fabric dependency to add my own. Hence even the need for Firebase Crash Reporting.
- Will the Fabric dependency and the inability to remove it from project be interfering with Firebase run script as well? I can't imagine why it should.

Links referenced:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/
- https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/settings/working-in-teams.html#add-organizations

Comment: Weird issue! I don't know what's causing Xcode to crash...that's pretty strange. But one thing I do know, is that you can't have two crash reporters installed at once (on iOS). So, I'd recommend just leaving out the Firebase/Crash pod and just use Crashlytics.

Comment: @mike_haney - How I wish I could! Fabric was configured into the project by another team and all my attempts at removing it failed with XCode crashes too. That's why I even went to look for other crash reporting solutions!

Comment: Fabric and Firebase Crash can't coexist--the OS only allows a single handler to be installed. If you have two crash reporters installed, the behavior is undefined. It seems unlikely that either of these are causing Xcode to crash. Do you have any Xcode plugins installed? Could you use a newer version of Xcode?

Comment: Also, Swift or ObjC?